# Count number of instances of a City object in a model syntax

Tags: python, django

I will briefly explain what I am trying to do.

A user will sign up with `email`, `first and last name`, and then select a `city` (handled by the model called `Waitlist`).

I am using `django_cities_light` for city selection.

I want to define a `queryset` that counts the number of times a specific city has been selected and then output that number onto my `template_name` page.

Ex) 3 users sign up, 2 people select `London` as their city, thus there are 2 instances of the `London` city object in my `Waitlist` model. I want to be able to do this easily for multiple cities.

I want to then render this `2` out using `{{ for London in waitlist.qs }}` for example (I'm not sure of the syntax hence why I'm asking).

I will show what I have done so far and if someone could explain to me how to define the queryset properly, I would appreciate it!

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        london = Waitlist.objects.get(??)
        context = {
            'london': london,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

models.py

```
class Waitlist(models.Model):
    first_name            = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    city            = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you need something like this, get all cities, and prepare data:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = Waitlist.objects.all()
        data = {}
        for cname in query.values('city__name').distinct():
            city = cname['city__name']
            data[city] = query.filter(city__name=city)
        context = {
            'data': data,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

and in the template

```
{% for city, details in data.items %}
    <strong>{{ city }}, total - {{ details|length }}:<strong>
    <ul>
    {% for wait_item in details %}
        <li>{{ wait_item.first_name }} - {{ wait_item.email }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

if you need only the `London`
in the view it should be:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = Waitlist.objects.filter(city__name__iexact='london')
         context = {
            'data': data,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

and in the template:

```
    <strong>London, total - {{ data|length }}:<strong>
    <ul>
    {% for wait_item in data %}
        <li>{{ wait_item.first_name }} - {{ wait_item.email }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

details for the query you can read [iexact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#iexact), [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: So for example, would I substitute `London` into `cname`? What would go into the data `{}`? Also I keep getting an error that the `return render` is indented incorrectly no matter how I format it.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are doing. But what is the proper syntax for `{% for city, details in the data.items %}` would it be `{% for london in data.items %}` ?

Comment: There is also an error being thrown `name 'query_order' is not defined`, would it be better with just `context`?

Comment: now i hope i created the finished answer, where the `count` for the city in the total for each city in the template.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Where can I learn more about how to do this and the syntax? One last question, if I only want to display `London` in the template and not a forloop of every city with an instance (there may be hundreds of different cities), what would the syntax be?

Comment: added some details hope it help you